# How to change " disk_free_limit " in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

Am using Ubuntu. I have installed RabbitMQ by downloading .deb file rabbitmq-server_3.3.4-1_all.deb

I'm unable to find my rabbitmq.config at this location `/etc/rabbitmq`

how to find it? Have I a mistake in installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [document](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html), the **rabbitmq.config** won't be created by default:

> **Location of rabbitmq.config and rabbitmq-env.conf**
>
> The location of these files is distribution-specific. By default, they are **not** created, but expect to be located in the following places on each platform:
>
> - Generic UNIX - $RABBITMQ_HOME/etc/rabbitmq/
> - Debian - /etc/rabbitmq/
> - RPM - /etc/rabbitmq/

you can find a sample config in **/usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server/** and copy it to **/etc/rabbitmq/**. And then you can change the **disk_free_limit** variable

Answer (score 4):

You may also update this value while broker is running.

In the command line of your RabbitMQ instance, use `rabbitmqctl set_disk_free_limit <absolute value>` or `rabbitmqctl set_disk_free_limit mem_relative <fraction>`.

See in [RabbitMQ Docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/disk-alarms.html).

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with my RabbitMQ all the queues are blocked, I used your command but isn't sworking, may you help me? please

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned at the [documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#example-config), you can find some example config files at:

- [basic config example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example)
- [advanced config example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/docs/advanced.config.example)

You can copy this file at the location for your specific distribution and change/add your configuration. Note that the **rabbitmq.config** is not created by default.

Comment: both links are broken